# Combining data from two listeners in Android

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I am working on an Android project(Tango) where it involves getting data from two event listeners and combine those values into a single JSON string and send it to a server.

The following code block states the two methods I want to read data from.

1. onPoseAvailable()
2. onPointCloudAvailable()

```java
mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.TangoUpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            // Get values from pose
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud) {
            // Get values from pointCloud
        }
}
```

I have to send a JSON string to server like the following format

```all
{
    pose:"pose value from onPoseAvailable",
    pointCloud:"pointCloud from onPointCloudAvailable",
    timeStamp:"time derived from fields available inside pose object"
}
```

Is there a technique or a method which I can use to combine both readings; pose and pointCloud at the same time as they are available in the method body so that I can concatenate both values into one JSON or a string?

Can I have a little tip? :) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why you don't declare a field for anonymous inner `callback`? Or just 1 outer final variable that can be a data container.

Answer (score 1):

if you need both methods to be called before you can send to the server, you can have 2 class fields with the last value for each callback, and then when a callback method is called it checks if the value of the other callback is there, if so send to the server all the data, if not, just keep the data for the next callback to be called. the implementation could look something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private TangoPoseData mLastTangoPoseData;
    private TangoPointCloudData mLastTantoPointCloudData;

    public void bar() {
        mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.TangoUpdateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
                mLastTangoPoseData = pose;
                sendToServer();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud) {
                mLastTantoPointCloudData = pointCloud;
                sendToServer();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendToServer() {
        if (mLastTangoPoseData == null || mLastTantoPointCloudData == null) return;

        makeApiCall(mLastTangoPoseData, mLastTantoPointCloudData);
        mLastTangoPoseData = null;
        mLastTantoPointCloudData = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a JSONObject, and store the required fields when the methods execute, for example

```
private org.json.JSONObject mJSONMap = new org.json.JSONObject();

mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.TangoUpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            // Get values from pose
            mJSONMap.put("pose" , "pose value from onPoseAvailable");
            mJSONMap.put("timeStamp" , "Do timestamp modifications here");
           doSomethingWithMap( mJSONMap ); 
        } 

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud) {
            // Get values from pointCloud
            mJSONMap.put("pointCloud" , "pointCloud from onPointCloudAvailable");
           doSomethingWithMap( mJSONMap ); 
        }

        private synchronized void doSomethingWithMap( org.json.JSONObject myMap )
        {
            System.out.println( myMap );
            // check to see if your map is populated with keys
            // from onPoseAvailable() and onPointCloudAvailable()?
            // We must have 3keys if BOTH THE METHOD CALLS COMPLETED
            if( myMap.length() == 3 )
            {
                //consume the map
                //Clear the map after you have consumed it
                // so that future callbacks 
                // do not mix values associated with previous callbacks
                myMap.remove("pose");
                myMap.remove("timeStamp");
                myMap.remove("pointCloud");

            }
        }
}
```

Now **doSomethingWithMap(org.json.JSONObject)** gets called either from **onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData)** or **onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData)** , therefore you must also **synchronize** access to this method. Hope it gives you some help, but will elaborate in more detail if needed